# log4j-core 2.17.1:ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

When I use log4j-api and log4j-core 2.17.1 version, the springboot application console reports an error:ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
[image]

Whatshould I do can make this error not reported on the console？

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The version of log4j-core is 2.12.1-sec and 2.1 in addition to 2.17.1

Comment: Waiting for your answer,THX！